# Yii2 Find all products in parent category

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have 2 tables structure as following:

```
category(id,cat_name , parent_id);
product(id,category_id ,pro_name);
```

Relation in Product Model

```
public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
    }  

Category

id   cat_name    parent_id
1    Electronic   0
2    Fruit        0
3    TV           1
4    Apple        2

Product
id category_id  pro_name
1  1            Samsung
2  3            Sony
3  3            Panasonic
4  2            Apple
5  2            Orange
```

What I want to do is when I select on category (1) Electronic
I want to get 
Samsung,Sony,Panasonic from table Product

Comment: add your respected sql and relation created in model.

Comment: What do you want to do? You have a sub category, and you want to display all products in the parent category?

Comment: @Jorgen yes what I want to do is to select all product in parent category and its sub category as well. Please help

Comment: add your sql also you tried so far

Comment: SELECT * FROM product p
JOIN category cp ON p.category_id = cp.id
JOIN category cc ON cp.parent_id = cc.id
WHERE cc.id = 1    but I don't know how to write it in active record  @InsaneSkull

Comment: If your models are already made simply do `$model->category->products`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// given $id is your current toplevel category
$cat_ids = Category::find()->select('id')->where(['parent_id' => $id])->asArray()->all();
$ids = [];
foreach($cat_ids as $value)
{
    $ids[] = $value['id'];
}
$ids = implode(',',$ids);
$categories = Products::find()->where('category_id IN ('.$ids.','.$id.')')->all();
```

Some object to array functionallity there that you might be able to clean up. This was quick and dirty, but should work. You get the point.

Comment: Wow Wow it's working fine. Thanks you so much. you saved my life

Comment: Yes, but its two queries - so not perfect. You can read up on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data and you might be able to make it into one.

Comment: This solution will only work with categories one level below . But what if the scenario have more than that? `MainCategory > SubCategory > SubSubCategory > etc`

Answer (score 3):

So, you must have a relational function in your `Category` model calling more Categories. And another relational function calling the Products. I'm assuming the names are `getParentId()` and `getProducts()`. (If you dont have, you can use [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) to generate them for you)

Here is a recursive approach you can do inside your `Category` model:

```
public function getSubCategories()
{
    if ($categories = $this->parentId) { // the name of your relational function.   
        foreach ($this->parentId as $sub) {
            $categories = array_merge($categories, $sub->subCategories);
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}

public function getProductsWithSubcategories()
{
    $products = $this->products; // the name of your relational function.   

    foreach ($this->subCategories as $sub) {
        $products = array_merge($products, $sub->products);
    }

    return $products;
}
```